# assigning a value to a pointer structure member in c

Tags: c, function

Im defining a c function and need to assign a value to members of a structure passed by address into the function, for example i defined the structure called cell:

```
typedef struct AB
{int A;
 char val;
}cell;
```

i wrote a function called Available where a cell is passed by address into the function. i need to fill the integer member A within the cell with a parameter given by the user, here is my approach.

```
void available(cell *c,int v)
{ *c.A=v;
 }
```

my question is am i able to do so? like *c.A=v?

Comment: c->A = v; just like classes

Comment: Regarding style: it is more consistent to use the same tag for the `struct` and the `typedef`: `typedef struct cell { ... } cell;`.  Also name your function with a verb, such as `set_available` or `cell_set_available`, it makes the code easier to read and understand.  Also do not use all uppercase member or function names.

Comment: Following the edit, it is unclear what the `available` function really does...

Comment: @MohamadMisto: I've rolled back the last edit - if you have a further question then please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would use the arrow operator:

```
c->A = v;
```

but you can also do it like this:

```
(*c).A = v;
```

Note that you need the parentheses to deal with operator precedence in this case.

Comment: `c->A = v;` is the same as `(*c).A = v;` or indeed `0[c].A = v;` but only for explanatory purposes.  Only use the first syntax in your code: `c->A = v;`

Comment: @MohamadMisto: if you have a further question then post it as a new question - don't keep editing your question beyond its original scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
(*c).A=v;
```

or

```
c->A=v;
```

instead of

```
*c.A=v;
```

Answer (score 1):

The valid assignment will look either like

```
void available( cell *c, int v )
{ 
   ( *c ).A = v;
}
```

or like

```
void available( cell *c, int v )
{ 
   c->A = v;
}
```